# Reverse Ajax module in django to build notification system

Tags: python, ajax, django, web

I am using python and django to build an application. I want to build notification system as in facebook notification. What I want is as soon as the database gets updated, a user gets notified about the changes. For that I don't want to use ajax and make asynchronous request every time-interval instead what I want is the server to push the changes to the client. Is that possible? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with http://socket.io

To use it with django Take a look at https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio

Answer (score -1):

You can learn how disqus did this from this presentation: https://speakerdeck.com/northisup/scaling-realtime-at-disqus

They use [nginx push stream module](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module)

> A pure stream http push technology for your Nginx setup.
>
> Comet made easy and really scalable.
>
> Supports EventSource, WebSocket, Long Polling, and Forever Iframe.